# Trigger event on scroll iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, scroll, touchmove

stackoverflow already helped me a lot whenever I dare to code by myself, but today I can't figure out something with the answers I found.

I have a simple jQuery script that works beautifully in every browser and on Android. Only my dear Apple screws around (both iPad and iPhone).

I have a sticky header that fades-in after a bit of scrolling. I figured that I need some kind of `touchmove` event, but nothing that I tried has worked.

Can you briefly explain how I have to change this piece of code to make it work?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {     
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
if (scroll > 220) {
    $("#stickyMenuProject").addClass("active");
}
else {
    $("#stickyMenuProject").removeClass("active");
}});
```

Help is much appreciated and I love that this forum exists!

kvn

P.S. If needed, here is the CSS:

```
#stickyMenuProject {
    height: 4rem;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(239,239,239,.0);
    padding-left: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 98;
}

#stickyMenuProject.active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(200,200,200,.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(175,175,175,.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(200,200,200,.5);
    transition: box-shadow .25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: box-shadow .25s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: box-shadow .25s ease-in-out;
    background-color: rgba(239,239,239,1);    
    -webkit-transition:background-color .5s;
    -moz-transition:background-color .5s;
    transition:background-color .5s;
```

Answer (score 0):

If this code doesn't work then it is probably a problem with the css, however I doubt that.

```
var scroll_pos = 0;
$(document).scroll(function() {
    scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scroll_pos > 20) {
        $("#stickyMenuProject").addClass("active");
    } else {
        $("#stickyMenuProject").removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. But you are saying 'touchmove' is not necessary?